# How do I put "L" exactly in the middle of the line?

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I, for example, have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[margin=2.625cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}



 \begin{document}


 \begin{tikzpicture}

 \fill (1.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, yshift=-0.03cm, 
  font=\small]{1};
 \draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (0.7,0.0) -- (1.5,1.5) 
  node[xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-0.7cm, font=\tiny]{L};

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

How do I put the "L" exactly in the middle of the line? I don't really understand how the xshift and yshift work. What is the shift comparing to?

Comment: Please don't post fragments of code. Instead put the fragment into a small compilable document that people can play with. Also you can format code in questions by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` icon in the editor.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you for your feedback. Is it okay like this?

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! For this example you don't actually need `graphicx`, or `subcaption` but extra packages are only problematic when you include your entire preamble into an example :) Asking questions like this  is what will allow people to help you much more efficiently.

Comment: @AlanMunn Alright thank you for your help!

Comment: But it looks like your goal is to simply add a label to a path, in which case you're complicating things unnecessarily. Try `\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (0.7,0.0) to [edge label={\tiny L}] (1.5,1.5);` instead.

Comment: Or use `node[midway]` or `[pos=0.5]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `\fill` for the circle, you can specify `Circle` as an arrow tip (requires the `arrows.meta` library). Then you can draw the line, both tips and both labels in one line.

Placing the `node` after `--` (or after `to`) will default to the middle of the segment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=2.625cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[stealth-Circle, line width=0.3pt] (0.7,0.0) --node[above left=-2pt, font=\tiny]{L} (1.5,1.5) node[above, font=\small]{1};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help!! If, however, I would like to draw more lines. How would that work? Like if there are 2 edges coming out of one vertex for example. Like this:
\draw[stealth-Circle, line width=0.3pt] (0.7,0.0) --node[above left=-2pt, font=\tiny]{L} 
         (1.5,1.5) node[above, font=\small]{2};
      \draw[stealth-Circle, line width=0.3pt] (1.5,1) --node[above left=-2pt, font=\tiny]{R} 
           (1.5,1.5);

Comment: In that case I would probably make a node for the point and give it a label and a name: `\draw[-stealth, line width=0.3pt] (1.5,1.5)node[draw, fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, label={[font=\small]above:1}](A){} --node[above left=-2pt, font=\tiny]{L} (0.7,0.0); \draw[-stealth, line width=0.3pt] (A) --node[right=-2pt, font=\tiny]{R}(1.5,1);` But this is really a new question so I would suggest you accept one of the answers for this question and then ask a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Earlier answers have focused on how to put the L in the middle of the line, which deals with the first of your questions, but say less about what `shift` is doing. One of the existing answers touches on your second question, but does not really explain it.

To understand what `xshift` and `yshift` do, you need to start by considering where the *un*shifted node would appear. The following diagram shows this position in red. If you just put the node there, this is where it would appear.

[image: diagram showing default position of node]

The default anchor is the `center` of the node, which is aligned with the `center` of the circular node.

`xshift=-0.5cm` just says to shift the node 0.5cm to the left. Let's show this in blue.

[image: effect of shifting 0.5cm left]

This means there will be 5mm between the centre of the red version and the centre of the blue one.

`yshift=-0.7cm` just says to shift the node 0.7cm down. Let's show this in green.

[image: effect of shifting 0.7cm down]

`xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-0.7cm` combines these two instructions so the node is moved 0.5cm to the left and 0.7cm down.

[image: effect of combining shifts]

That is,

[image: diagram to accompany explanation of xshift and yshift]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every pin/.append style={font=\tiny,help lines,inner sep=1pt},every pin edge/.append style={help lines,densely dashed,{Circle[length=1pt]}-,shorten <=-.5pt},explan/.style={font=\tiny,densely dashed,draw}]
  \fill (1.5,1.5) coordinate (c1) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, yshift=-0.03cm, font=\small]{1};
  \draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth,red] (0.7,0) coordinate (c2) -- (c1) node[explan,pin=45:default]{L};
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \draw [help lines,densely dashed] (c1) edge +(1,0) edge +(-1,0) edge +(0,1) -- +(0,-1);
    \draw [help lines,densely dashed] (c1) ++(-0.5,-0.7) edge +(1.5,0) edge +(-0.5,0) edge +(0,1.7) -- +(0,-0.3);
    \draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth,blue] (c2) -- (c1) node[xshift=-0.5cm, explan,pin=135:5mm left]{L};
    \draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth,green] (c2) -- (c1) node[yshift=-0.7cm, explan,pin=-45:7mm down]{L};
    \draw [densely dashed,blue] (c1) -- ++(-0.5cm,0) coordinate [midway,pin=above:5mm] (c3) ;
    \draw [densely dashed,green] (c1) -- ++(0,-0.7cm) coordinate [midway,pin=right:7mm] (c4) ;
  \end{scope}
  \draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (c2) -- (c1) node[xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-0.7cm, font=\tiny,pin=-135:5mm left 7mm down]{L};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways to do it, in red and green.

- `xshift`, `yshift` do what they say: shift by a given amount
- IF you know the lengths involved, that's fine
- WHEN you don't using `midway` or `pos` is better
- where `midway` simply is `pos=.5`

BTW, the green text, as well as the left/right keyword, seem to a appear on the wrong side, as you put `<-` , i.e. the arrow at the start, then a line, and then no arrow at the end.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[margin=2.625cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}

 \fill (1.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.05] 
                 node[above, yshift=-0.03cm, font=\small] {1};
 \draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (0.7,0.0) -- (1.5,1.5) 
                node[xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-0.7cm, font=\tiny]{L}
                node[red,midway,right]{+}
                node[green,pos=0.2,right]{+};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[margin=2.625cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (1.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, yshift=-0.03cm, 
        font=\small]{1};
        \draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (0.7,0.0) -- (1.5,1.5) 
        node[pos=.5, font=\tiny,fill=white]{L};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```