# How do I put "L" and "R" exactly in the middle of my tikz lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

As a follow up question on my last question. If I would have the following graph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[margin=2.625cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (1.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, yshift=-0.03cm, font=\small]{2} ;
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (0.7,0.0) -- (1.5,1.5) node[xshift=-0.4cm, 
 yshift=-0.5cm, font=\tiny]{L};
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (1.5,1) -- (1.5,1.5) node[xshift=0.4cm, yshift=-0.13cm, 
 font=\tiny]{R};

\fill (1.5,1) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.1cm, yshift=-0.03cm, font=\small]{3};
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (0.7,0.0) -- (1.5,1) node[xshift=-0.2cm, yshift=-0.1cm, 
font=\tiny]{L};
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (2.3,1) -- (1.5,1) node[xshift=0.35cm, yshift=0.1cm, font=\tiny]{R};

\fill (2.3,1) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, yshift=-0.03cm, font=\small]{4};
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (2.3,0.0) -- (2.3,1) node[xshift=0.1cm, yshift=-0.4cm, font=\tiny]{L};
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (1.5,1.5) -- (2.3,1) node[above, xshift=-0.9cm, yshift=0cm, font=\tiny]{R};

\fill (1.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.1cm, yshift=-0.03cm, font=\small]{5};
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (0.7,0)-- (1.5,0.5) node[xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=-0.05cm, font=\tiny]{L};
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (1.5,1)  -- (1.5,0.5) node[pos=0.5, font=\tiny]{R};

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

How do I put the "L" and "R" exactly in the middle of the line? It is really a pain to try to do it with the xshift and yshift.

Comment: Does the answer from your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706435/270231) not work for your use case? Also, you use the node option `pos=0.5` in one of your `\draw` commands; does that not work for this either?

Comment: I have done a complete answer to Yours similar previous question. Now what you ask exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the node on the path and not at the end, I added midway and sloped for the inclined links

I'll let you improve this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[margin=2.625cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\fill (1.5,1.5) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, yshift=-0.03cm, font=\small]{2} ;
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (0.7,0.0) --node[midway,sloped, above,
font=\tiny]{L}  (1.5,1.5) ;
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (1.5,1) --node[midway,right,
 font=\tiny]{R} (1.5,1.5) ;

\fill (1.5,1) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.1cm, yshift=-0.03cm, font=\small]{3};
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (0.7,0.0) --node[midway,sloped, above,
font=\tiny]{L} (1.5,1) ;
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (2.3,1) --node[midway,above, font=\tiny]{R} (1.5,1) ;

\fill (2.3,1) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, yshift=-0.03cm, font=\small]{4};
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth] (2.3,0.0) --  node[midway,right, font=\tiny]{L}(2.3,1);
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth,brown] (1.5,1.5) -- node[above,sloped,midway, font=\tiny]{R}(2.3,1) ;

\fill (1.5,0.5) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.1cm, yshift=-0.03cm, font=\small]{5};
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth,blue] (0.7,0)-- node[midway,above,sloped, font=\tiny]{L}(1.5,0.5) ;
\draw[<-, line width=0.3pt, >=stealth,red] (1.5,1)  -- node[pos=0.5, right,font=\tiny]{R} (1.5,0.5) ;

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! Is there also a way to put the L and R closer to the line?

Comment: by searching a little in the documentation, you should find it!
https://s.42l.fr/GoogleIsYourFriend